# How to resolve Consider preallocating (prealloc) lint?

Tags: go, slice, lint

I catch `Consider preallocating [to] (prealloc)` this problen in `golangci-lint`
my code is:

```
var to []string
for _, t := range s.To {
    to = append(to, t.String())
}
```

Do you have an idea to resolve this problem in lint?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Preallocate a slice with capacity so [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) will have less (or no) copying to do:

```
to := make([]string, 0, len(s.To))
for _, t := range s.To {
    to = append(to, t.String())
}
```

Or even better, don't use `append()` but assign to individual slice elements:

```
to := make([]string, len(s.To))
for i, t := range s.To {
    to[i] = t.String()
}
```

Comment: Pay close attention to the difference between the two `make`s here - you must set cap to 0 if you're using `append` and you must not set it to 0 when using direct indexing.

Comment: Gah you're right, I guess I haven't had enough coffee today...

Comment: If you want to deepen your understanding I found this article very helpful, it explains the difference between slice and array with code examples and uses both of the above solutions: [Calhoun](https://www.calhoun.io/how-to-use-slice-capacity-and-length-in-go/)

Answer (score 0):

The following will also make the lint error go away:

```golang
to := []string{}
```